# Не работает formfield_for_manytomany() в админке

Tags: python, django

У меня в админке идет отображение в inline данных, которые связаны отношением ManyToMany. Я хочу, чтобы мне выдавались данные в inline для выбора только отфильтрованные. Я использую для этого formfield_for_manytomany, но ничего не происходит. В чем моя ошибка?

**models.py**

```
class UniversityTransaction(models.Model):
    bundles = models.ManyToManyField('store.Bundle', through='BundleTransaction')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.code


class BundleTransaction(models.Model):
    bundle = models.ForeignKey('store.Bundle', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    university_transaction = models.ForeignKey(UniversityTransaction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**admin.py**

```
class BundleInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = BundleTransaction
    extra = 0
    fields = ('bundle', 'expired', 'limit')
    readonly_fields = ('users',)

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if obj and obj.status == UniversityTransaction.APPROVED:
            return super(BundleInline, self).get_readonly_fields(request) + ('limit',)

        return super(BundleInline, self).get_readonly_fields(request)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        codes = [
            'first_data',
            'second_data',
            'third_data'
        ]

        if db_field.name == 'bundles':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Bundle.objects.filter(code__in=codes)
            print(kwargs['queryset'])
        return super(BundleInline, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)


@admin.register(UniversityTransaction)
class UniversityTransactionAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('code', 'university', 'status')
    readonly_fields = ('code', 'status', 'email')
    inlines = [BundleInline]
    search_fields = ('code',)
```

Answer (score 0):

Помогло следующие:

```
def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        codes = [
            'first_data',
            'second_data',
            'third_data'
        ]

        if db_field.name == 'bundles':
            kwargs['queryset'] = Bundle.objects.filter(code__in=codes)
            print(kwargs['queryset'])
        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```